# Storing a std::function as a private member results in it being null when used

Tags: c++, function, qt, callback

I am at a loss for why this isn't working. I've tried passing a function by value, by reference, and still when I go to call the function from within `SetFromState`, it is null.

My class:

```
StateIndicator::StateIndicator(QWidget *parent) {
    StateIndicator(parent, StateIndicator::DefaultSelectionStrategy);
}

StateIndicator::StateIndicator(QWidget *parent,
                               const std::function<std::string (State)>& selectionStrategy)
    :QWidget(parent),
     selection_strategy_(selectionStrategy)
{
    wrapped = new QLabel(this);
}

void StateIndicator::SetFromState(State state)
{
    std::string resourcePath = selection_strategy_(state);
    wrapped->setTextFormat(Qt::TextFormat::RichText);
    char* buffer = new char[StateIndicator::label_format.length() + resourcePath .length()];
    sprintf(buffer, label_format.c_str(), resourcePath .c_str());
    wrapped->setText(buffer);
}

std::string TruckStateIndicator::DefaultSelectionStrategy(State state){
    return ":img/Disconnected";
}
```

call:

```
StateIndicator* state = new StateIndicator(this);
ui->leftPaneLayout->insertWidget(1,state);
state->SetFromState(State::Connected);
```

When I use the debugger, in my constructor it shows that my selection strategy is set. But when I get to the call to `SetFromState` the private member `selection_strategy_` is null.

However, my code works if within the `SetFromState` function I instead change it to:

```
std::function<std::string(TruckState)> strategy = &DefaultSelectionStrategy;
std::string path = strategy(state);
```

and assign the variable right there. It feels like something is going out of scope and causing my function pointer to become null, but I'm pretty much stuck.

Edited:
Here is the header file. I will also try to make the example minimal by removing the inheritance and trying to reproduce

```
#ifndef STATEINDICATOR_H
#define STATEINDICATOR_H

#include <QLabel>
#include "src/models/state.h"

class StateIndicator : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit StateIndicator(QWidget* parent);
    explicit StateIndicator(QWidget* parent,
                            const std::function<std::string (State)>& selectionStrategy);
    void SetFromState(State state);
private:
     static std::string DefaultSelectionStrategy(State state);
     QLabel* wrapped;
     const std::function<std::string(State)> image_selection_strategy_;

     inline const static std::string label_format = "&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;"
                                "img src=&quot;%s&quot;/&gt;"
                                "&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;";
};

#endif // TRUCKSTATEINDICATOR_H
```

Comment: A side note: I think you have a memory leak in `SetFromState`: you never `delete[] buffer`.

Comment: So the problem is initializing `resourcePath`? If that's the case, a simpler `SetFromState()` could demonstrate the problem. Make it two lines. Replace everything after the first line with `std::cerr << "Resource path: '" << resourcePath << "'\n";`. It looks like you could then eliminate the `QWidget*` parameter from the constructor and drop Qt from your question. Simplifying is good (for both people answering and for future visitors with the same question).

Comment: Probably need to provide a definition for `StateIndicator`. This would be the "reproducible" part of [mre]. If you apply the "minimal" part as well, the definition should be pretty simple -- no inheritance, no member functions other than what's already in the question, and no data members other than `selection_strategy_` (which is not a reference, right?).

Comment: I don't see the bug, so I think a [mre] is needed to figure this out.

Comment: @paolo, yup i do. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how I was calling the overloaded constructor it seems:

```
StateIndicator::StateIndicator(QWidget *parent) {
    StateIndicator(parent, StateIndicator::DefaultSelectionStrategy);
}
```

should be

```
StateIndicator::StateIndicator(QWidget *parent) :
    StateIndicator(parent, StateIndicator::DefaultSelectionStrategy)
{
}
```